# Element.style on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When I change the color to #ab8d2c on Google Inspect Tool it works fine. But when I add it on Wordpress additional CSS, I am not able to get the same result. How do I fix this?

```
element.style {
background: #ab8d2c url(http://localhost/demo5/wp-content/themes/piko-construct/assets/images/bg/page-title.jpg) repeat center center;
```

}

Comment: Element.style means that is is a style set on the element's style="" attribute.  So you have to change it on the ellement itself. What do you wnat to change on what page/url?

Comment: You can try  .header-wrapper .page-header.has-bg-img { background: #ab8d2c url(http://localhost/demo5/wp-content/themes/piko-construct/assets/images/bg/page-title.jpg) repeat center center !important; }